# How to initialize a select2 disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, ui-select2, angularjs-select2

I have a simple select2 init which I want to be **disabled by default** without chaining a `.select2("enable", false)` afterwards.

HTML:

```
<input type='hidden' value="192" data-init-text='Bla bla' name="input" id="test" style="width:300px;" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').select2({
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        placeholder: "Search",
        enable: "false", // I want this to be working!
        ajax: {
            url: "http://www.weighttraining.com/sm/search",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            quietMillis: 100,
            data: function(term, page) {
                return {
                    types: ["exercise"],
                    limit: -1,
                    term: term
                };
            },
            results: function(data, page ) {
                return { results: data.results.exercise }
            }
        },
        formatResult: function(exercise) { 
            return "<div class='select2-user-result'>" + exercise.term + "</div>"; 
        },
        formatSelection: function(exercise) { 
            return exercise.term; 
        },
        initSelection : function (element, callback) {
            var elementText = $(element).attr('data-init-text');
            callback({"term":elementText});
        }
    });
});
```

See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUsMb/3632/) for an example. [Select2 Docs here](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#doc-query).

Comment: From the documentation you provided, that plugin does not support such an option in its constructor. I understand you *want this to be working*, but the functionality is just not there. You can either modify the plugin, or live with a chained call to `select2("enable", false)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply add the `disabled`attribute to your input.

```
<input disabled type='hidden' value="192" data-init-text='Bla bla' name="input" id="test" style="width:300px;" />
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').select2({
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        placeholder: "Search",
        ajax: {
            url: "http://www.weighttraining.com/sm/search",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            quietMillis: 100,
            data: function(term, page) {
                return {
                    types: ["exercise"],
                    limit: -1,
                    term: term
                };
            },
            results: function(data, page ) {
                return { results: data.results.exercise }
            }
        },
        formatResult: function(exercise) { 
            return "<div class='select2-user-result'>" + exercise.term + "</div>"; 
        },
        formatSelection: function(exercise) { 
            return exercise.term; 
        },
        initSelection : function (element, callback) {
            var elementText = $(element).attr('data-init-text');
            callback({"term":elementText});
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2.0/select2.min.js"></script>
<input disabled type='hidden' value="192" data-init-text='Bla bla' name="input" id="test" style="width:300px;" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUsMb/3634/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').select2({
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        placeholder: "Search",
        ajax: {
            url: "http://www.weighttraining.com/sm/search",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            quietMillis: 100,
            data: function(term, page) {
                return {
                    types: ["exercise"],
                    limit: -1,
                    term: term
                };
            },
            results: function(data, page ) {
                return { results: data.results.exercise }
            }
        },
        formatResult: function(exercise) { 
            return "<div class='select2-user-result'>" + exercise.term + "</div>"; 
        },
        formatSelection: function(exercise) { 
            return exercise.term; 
        },
        initSelection : function (element, callback) {
            var elementText = $(element).attr('data-init-text');
            callback({"term":elementText});
        }
    }).select2("enable", false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am including the latest working code below:

```
$("your-selector").select2({
  // configuration params
}).prop("disabled", true);
```

Notice the `prop` method. Pretty simple, right?